# POST JSON array with indices using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to POST a json array to server. Data is something like this:

```
{something:
    {somethings:
        [
            {"param1":"value", "param2":value},
            {"param1":"value", "param2":value}
        ]
    }
}
```

however, my server forces me to MUST include the indices in the array like:

```
{something:
    {somethings:
        {
         "0":{"param1":"value", "param2":value},
         "1":{"param1":"value", "param2":value}
        }
    }
}
```

In other words  cannot send parameters like this:

```
something[somethings][][param1]
something[somethings][][param2]
```

I must include indices:

```
something[somethings][0][param1]
something[somethings][0][param2]
```

How to do this using retrofit?

My interface looks like this:

```
interface ApiService {
    @POST("endpoint")
    public Callback<Something> postSomething (@Body Something something);
}
```

My classes look like following:

```
public class PostSomething {
    private MapOfSomething something = new MapOfSomething();

    public MapOfSomething getSomething() {
        return portfolio;
    }

    public void setSomething(MapOfSomething something) {
        this.something = something;
    }
}

public class MapOfSomething {
    private JSONObject somethings = new JSONObject();

    public JSONObject getPortfolios() {
        return somethings;
    }

    public void setSomethings(List<Something> somethingList) {

        for (int i = 0; i<somethingList.size(); i++) {

            try {
                somethings.put(String.valueOf(i).toString(), somethingList.get(i));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

and calling the method like:

```
PostSomethings something = new PostSomethings();
MapOfSomething map = new mapOfSomething();
map.setSomethings(listofSomething);
something.setSomethings(map);
apiService.postSomething(something);
```

Comment: your second json format is wrong. Inside json array you cant put value like 0:{"param1":"value", "param2":value} this.

Comment: yeah the syntax can be wrong, i'm not very much familiar with it. but the key point is, the server expects indices of the array. i cannot POST array without indices.

Comment: then you can manually create json and send as String

Comment: could you share the code of your interface ?

Comment: @shuvro I've edited my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to put json directly into body , so your interface will look like this

```
interface ApiService {
    @POST("endpoint")
    public Callback<Something> postSomething (@Body JSONObject jsonObject);
}
```

Now you need to create the JSONObject , here is how I have created your desired JSONObject

```
    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject singleElement1 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        singleElement1.put("param1","value1");
        singleElement1.put("param2","value2");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject singleElementSet1 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        singleElementSet1.put("1",singleElement1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONObject singleElement2 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        singleElement2.put("param1","value1");
        singleElement2.put("param2","value2");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject singleElementSet2 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        singleElementSet2.put("2",singleElement2);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    list.put(singleElementSet1);
    list.put(singleElementSet2);


    JSONObject subJson = new JSONObject();

    try {
        subJson.put("something",list);
        mainJson.put("something",subJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Log.d("json",""+mainJson.toString());
```

I am assuming right now you are calling your service like this way

```
  Call<Something> call = instanceOfYourAPIService.postSomething(anInstanceOfSomethingObject);
```

But now you have to replace this with the following

```
  Call<Something> call = instanceOfYourAPIService.postSomething(mainJson); //mainJson is the JSONObject which is created earlier
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

```
        JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject singleElement1 = new JSONObject();

        try {
            singleElement1.put("param1","value1");
            singleElement1.put("param2","value2");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JSONObject singleElement2 = new JSONObject();

        try {
            singleElement2.put("param1","value1");
            singleElement2.put("param2","value2");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        //hope you can add item to this arraylist via some loop
        jsonObjectArrayList.add(singleElement1);
        jsonObjectArrayList.add(singleElement2);



        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();


        for(int i = 0;i<jsonObjectArrayList.size();i++){


            JSONObject elementSet = new JSONObject();
            try {
                elementSet.put(String.valueOf(i).toString(),jsonObjectArrayList.get(i));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            list.put(elementSet);
        }


        JSONObject subJson = new JSONObject();

        try {
            subJson.put("something",list);
            mainJson.put("something",subJson);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it looks like you've assumed that there are only two elements in my JSON array. Actually it can be a thousand elements in the array

Comment: I don't exactly know the number of elements in the array

Comment: I am assuming you are creating  such array by iterating through a list or arraylist . Check my edit , by which you can any number of elements

Comment: there's a little problem. 
now my string looks like this:

Comment: @MuhammadArsal look like what?

Comment: {"something":{"somethings":{"nameValuePairs":{"0":{"param1":1,"param2":"value, "1":{"param1":2,"param2":"value"}}}}

Comment: i just want to eleminate "namevaluepairs"

Comment: sorry for not being clear before, I'm trying to say i want my string to look like this:
{"something":{"somethings":{"0":{"param1":‌​1,"param2":"value}, "1":{"param1":2,"param2":"value"}}}}

looks like I'm almost there.

Comment: i'm extremely sorry for not being clear with my question. I'm using nested java classes. I'm editing my question to add code of my classes

Comment: its ok , it would be better if you share the way you have generated your json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126511/discussion-between-muhammad-arsal-and-shuvro).